# Why does the local::lib shell code use eval and $()

Tags: shell, shell-script, posix

using [local::lib](http://search.cpan.org/dist/local-lib/lib/local/lib.pm) requires you to add a line to your `~/.shellrc`

```
eval $(perl -I$HOME/perl5/lib/perl5 -Mlocal::lib)
```

I don't understand what the point of using `eval`, and encasing the statement in `$()` is. I also notices that `csh` doesn't require you to use those. So I'm wondering what the difference is, and whether or not I should use this for generic bourne shell, or `zsh`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`perl -I$HOME/perl5/lib/perl5 -Mlocal::lib` prints out some shell code. The point of `eval $(…)` is to execute that code in the context of the current shell. This is typically used to set environment variables. You can't use a subprocess for this as this would only affect the subprocess's environment. You can source a snippet:

```
. /path/to/snippet-containing-variable-definitions
```

but that only works if the code that generates the variable values is written in shell. Here that code is written in Perl, so the Perl code generates shell code.

[dircolors](http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/dircolors-invocation.html) uses the same technique, as do many other programs.

The shell snippets are generally kept very simple, just variable assignments (with plain strings for values) and `export` statements, so they are compatible with all Bourne-style shells (including any POSIX shell) and zsh. `local::lib` is gratuitously incompatible with some decade-old systems as it combines `export` with assignment (which is permitted by POSIX but not by the original Bourne shell). Csh requires a different syntax; local::lib emits csh syntax if `$SHELL` contains `csh` as a substring. Under Windows, local::lib generates the equivalent cmd syntax; because cmd has no equivalent .

Comment: It's probably simplest to understand if you just run the command inside the `$()` and look at what it prints.  That's what the shell will eval.  Just to be clear, `$()` is the new-fangled way of writing backticks (command interpolation)... it's nice because it's easily nestable.  Otherwise there's not much difference.